# Erlang: high memory usage for processing list of binary parts

Tags: performance, memory, erlang

I have problem with huge memory usage in Erlang. Reducing my problem (part of MapReduce framework) to minimum, consider this code:

```
{match, Idx} = re:run(SomeBinary, <<"[A-Za-z0-9_]+">>,[global]),
List = [ {binary:part(SomeBinary, Pos, Len), 1}  || [{Pos, Len}] <- Idx],   
Sorted = lists:keysort(1, List),
```

Processing 15 MB binary UTF-8 encoded text with 2672923 words, has memory usage cap at 2 GB.
1,2 GB for regexp part, rest 800MB for keysort().

Even with all linked list stuff, references etc. how is this possible?
When I "pause" process after computation, memory usage is after few seconds reduced to 300MB. I'm running Erlang R16B03 on archlinux.

PS 1: I've also tried returning binary directly from regexp but memory usage was same, performance little worse.

PS 2: Processing 30 MB file totally kills my RAM and lead to swapping.

PS 3: Same logic implemented in Rust, linked to PCRE lib for regexp (erlang uses PCRE too) has memory cap at 200 MB

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://blog.bugsense.com/post/74179424069/erlang-binary-garbage-collection-a-love-hate

Comment: Interesting read but i think it's not the same issue. They have problem with no longer used binaries which hangs in heap until garbage collection. Here is just one big binary and many part references into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend show me partial solution.
Instead of using regexp, manual tokenizer performs much better:

```
[{X, 1} || X <- words(Bin)].

words(Bin) ->
    words_2(Bin, [], []).

words_2(<<C, Rest/binary>>, CAcc, WAcc) when
        (C >= $A) and (C =< $Z);
        (C >= $a) and (C =< $z);
        (C >= $0) and (C =< $9);
        C =:= $_ ->
    words_2(Rest, [C | CAcc], WAcc);
words_2(<<_, Rest/binary>>, [], WAcc) ->
    words_2(Rest, [], WAcc);
words_2(<<>>, [], WAcc) ->
    lists:reverse(WAcc);
words_2(Rest, CAcc, WAcc) ->
    words_2(Rest, [], [list_to_binary(lists:reverse(CAcc)) | WAcc]).
```

This reduces 1,2 GB memory usage of regexp to acceptable value.
Unfortunately, 800 MB for lists:keysort(...) seems like tradeof for using erlang.

RegExps performs often significantly worse than "hand written" code. In case when speed is not limiting factor, RegExp is good for it's readability and easy modifications.

Despite general RegExps performance issues, high memory usage in this example seems like problem in internal implementation of Erlang/PCRE bindings in "re" module.

Answer (score 1):

A way to tokenize a binary that could potentially be very fast is binary:split/3 (although I have not tested it). If you use the global option and split on any character that is not alphanumeric you could get a list of words in a single call:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#split-3

Check out example 2.

Edit: For clarification, the following would split the binary on all spaces, points, commas and brackets and sort the results:

lists:sort(binary:split(Bin, [<<" ">>, <<".">>, <<",">>, <<"(">>, <<")">>], [global])).

This could however make you end up with empty strings in the resulting list, for example if there are more than one spaces in a row. If this is a problem they could be filtered afterwards.